# Как сделать 301 redirect, используя RewriteRule?

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

Нужно сделать такой редирект с folder/page  на folder/page/.

Спасите - помогите, ибо замучался.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте варианты отсюда: [301 редирект – корректная переадресация через htaccess и php header](http://sb-money.ru/article.php?a=75)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за страницу, но увы. А делается это, если кому вдруг понадобится, так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-dRewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-fRewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\/folder\/page$RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Впрочем, возможно, существуют более красивое/простое решение. Ежели кто знает, было бы интересно :)

Comment: Дык оформите это как ответ на свой вопрос - чтоб если кому понадобиться, видели, что у вопроса есть ответ ;)

Comment: Этого будет вполне достаточно RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.\/folder\/page$ RewriteRule ^(.)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]